# Can't exchange authorization code for tokens using Google OAuth2 in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

My code is here:
google.php at `http://127.0.0.1/projects/google/google.php`:

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1/projects/google/google.php';
$scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly';
$api_key ='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$code = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Drive PHP SDK APP NAME");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope($scope);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setDeveloperKey($api_key);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
echo $authUrl;

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    // >>>ERROR HERE<<<
}


$driveSdk = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$result = $driveSdk->files->listFiles();
```

after I visit $authUrl (`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fprojects%2Fgoogle%2Fgoogle.php&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.readonly&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto`)

I get code back from google like `http://127.0.0.1/projects/google/google.php?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

and I use it in $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

but instead of exchanging auth code for tokens I got `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_client'' in D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:132 Stack trace: #0 D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(130): Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('4/v-8aFUcb0YyPS...') #1 D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\google\google.php(31): Google_Client->authenticate('4/v-8aFUcb0YyPS...') #2 {main} thrown in D:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 132`

I logged CURL:
Request HTTP header was:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 Host: accounts.google.com Accept: */* content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-length: 291
```

Request post body was:

```
code=4%2FSevLUuq8mtyfUYYb2FSZ5Q5mYexF.smYRm3eONugRPvB8fYmgkJzTRFXKkQI&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fprojects%2Fgoogle%2Fgoogle.php&client_id=360693274514-a9orr65tr5f9elsfkfng2htls6cr308b.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=Gb02td3zZv1T01IQt-sGlFVwH
```

And response was:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: application/json Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Date: Mon, 06 Oct 2014 11:36:42 GMT X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01 Transfer-Encoding: chunked { "error" : "invalid_client" }
```

Seems like everything done right but still error.

I just can't get it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with line 115 of Google SDK, please double check your $client_id.  Seems like the response error is correct.